# Action controller exception sql 2008 connectivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to an external database to run reports off of.  This is a sql server 2008 database.

Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

I have added the following lines in my gem file and have run bundle install

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '4.2.10'
```

Also, this is an additional database outside of the normal set.

```
npr:  
      adapter: sqlserver  
      host: *****  
      port: 1433  
      database: *****  
      username: *****  
      password: *****  
      encoding: utf8
```

I have not found a good answer to why this is not working currently.

**edit**

Database does connect correctly in the rails console gem files are installed and in the gemfile.lock.

Comment: and you have verified that the gems are installed, and they show up in your lockfile?    and you have verified correct spacing in your database.yml file?

Comment: have you run a port scanner on the server to make sure that SQL is on port 1433? I deal with a couple of servers that are on other ports.

Comment: gems are installed and showing up iun lockfile  I think the spacing is correct in the database.yml.

Comment: port is confirmed as 1433

Answer (score 0):

I would first try in the ruby (not rails) console to make it work with tinyTDS:

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: 'mydb.host.net'
```

After that, you'll know if the problem comes from the DB setup (MSSQL in your case) or from your Rails config. Get back to us in the comments.

Comment: When running the command you suggested I got the following response:   
<TinyTds::Client:0x0055c17fb72b90 @query_options={:as=>:hash, :symbolize_keys=>false, :cache_rows=>true, :timezone=>:local, :empty_sets=>true}>

Comment: And then, you just need to see if it works: `client.active?` (this is all on https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds by the way)

Comment: the queries against that database are working properly.  It looks like a rails config issue and I'm unclear what that is with the config the way I have it.